# How to read pdf file in ios .I am not using UIWebView

Tags: ios

I want to read a pdf file which is coming in URl from server. I am not using UIWebview.

So, i just want to know that is there any way to view that pdf file without downloading in to device. Just it be readable or buffered, not stored.

Any suggestions for that.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to show a PDF outside of a UIWebView is using the QuickLook framework:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html

However, as isn't unreasonable, Quicklook requires URLs of a "file" type.

So without using a UIWebView, you'll need to add your own code to download/cache/display, which isn't hard. If you need sample code, let me know.

Comment: If it worked out for you, you could accept this answer.